# Why do images from Dropbox not load when running stack snippets?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#head{
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#main{
    width: 600px;
    height: 392px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">set in middle and center</div>
<div id="main">
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhvfyxq9cjx6rc5/i1.png?dl=0" alt="">
</div>
```

Why does the image from Dropbox fail to load when pressing "Run code snippet"?

Comment: "Blocked current origin from receiving cross-site document at https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhvfyxq9cjx6rc5/i1.png?dl=0 with MIME type text/html."

Comment: How can i  use my image to have a discussion  now?

Comment: Does it work if you use the provided `i.stack.imgur.com` image links from the post editor?

Comment: There's a reason you can upload images to SO using Imgur.

Comment: ...So I'm confused; what's actually *wrong* with the question again?

Comment: @Makoto: The code isn't broken by a Stack Snippets limitation, it's broken *everywhere*.  The URL given is not even an image URL.  Not being about the Stack Overflow platform makes it off-topic for meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely works if you upload this image to Stack Overflow's Imgur instance.

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#head{
    width:600px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#main{
    width:600px;
    height:392px;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">set in middle and center</div>
<div id="main">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnLnl.png" alt="">
</div>
```

The reason for this was probably for security's sake.  Depending on the image host, you may not get the *raw* image; you may get a link to what looks like an image but executes other JavaScript in the background.  That's what appears to have happened with Dropbox since I get taken to a full-fledged HTML page with its own JavaScript, and if that executes through Stack Snippets, we've got a cross-site scripting vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Upload the image to i.stack.imgur.com when you write a post on Stack Overflow, get the URL, and use it in snippets.

Comment: There's also a bunch of image placeholder services if what's in the image itself doesn't matter.